# Drupal 7,x campaigns

Tags: drupal

I'm just getting started with civicrm and I've noticed that campaigns are mentioned in a lot of instructional resources

However, I downloaded the latest instillation of civicrm and there's no campaign feature in the menu, and I can't find any campaign module that I've seen mentioned.

How do I activate campaigns?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable the Campaigns component:  go to `Administer > System Settings > Components` and make sure CiviCampaign is enabled